# The Scope attribute in th tags - when does it stop?

Tags: html

Scenario:

- Table with two tbody's
- First tbody has a th with a scope="col" applied.
- First tbody closes.
- Second tbody opens - it too has a th - this needs a scope="col" applied as well.
- Let's say for arguments sake the th's are in the same column.

The question: Does the first scope stop when it reaches the second tbody? the next scope? or does it stop at all?

If you have any tutorials or insights, I'm all ears.

Thanks.

Comment: So you're saying my first th is say <pre><th scope="col">Le content</th></pre> it follows down the col, and then it hits the <pre></tbody></pre> we have a new th - and it is<pre><th scope="col">Le different content</th></pre> - that the first scope will continue to overide the following?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I haven't tried it, but the various scope descriptions in the [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#adef-scope) all have the format "The current cell provides header information for the rest of the [type] that contains it," where [type] is the value of the scope attribute.

So, it sounds like it will apply to the entirety of the table, not just each tbody section.

Incidentally, since it says "the rest," it's also implied that another cell with the same scope will be the new header for any cells that follow it.